# Excel VBA: How to stop iteration when it start producing the same results as last iteration?

Tags: excel, vba

For something like the code below..

```
 For i = 0 to 40
     R  = R & "," & Application.WorksheetFunction.Min((Cell.Value + i * 5/8), 0.8) 
 Next i
```

How can I stop it when R starts producing the same result as last iteration (for example, i = 11 and i =12 producing the same result..)

I tried something like 
`If i = i - 1` `Then`
`Exit for` 
`End If`
but VBA cannot read it

Comment: You need to store your previous result in some variable, and then compare it to the current result, then Exit For if equal. You have not provided enough context/code to really offer a complete solution. `i` is not even used in your code here, so it's not clear how a different `i` value would yield different results (e.g., from the `Min` function?).

Comment: Oh It is actually `i `instead of `j` in the formula

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your previous result in some variable, and then compare it to the current result, then Exit For if equal.

```
Dim previousResult as Double
Dim thisResult as Double
For i = 0 to 40
    previousResult = thisResult
    thisResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min((Cell.Value + i * 5/8), 0.8) 
    If previousResult = thisResult Then Exit For
    R  = R & "," & thisResult

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add another variable that stores the previous iteration's result before doing work to the current iteration's variable. Then you just compare them and exit the loop if they match.

```
For i = 0 to 40
    Rprev = R
    R  = R & "," & Application.WorksheetFunction.Min((Cell.Value + j * 5/8), 0.8)
    If R = Rprev Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This is almost certainly incorrect, as `R` is a concatenated string that grows with each iteration, setting `Rprev = R` will never meet the later condition `If R = RPrev` because `R` changes before you do the comparison.

Comment: You're right, didn't think of that. The current iteration R will always have at least another "," added on.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if the Cell.values is a row of number instead of a single cell. How that works?